# Trigger a countdown when a set interval function is called

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, setinterval, countdown

I am retrieving a random user every 60sec via ajax get. In addition I want to trigger a timer which indicates the user when the next 'random user' will be displayed.

I have tried to create two separate functions, one for the ajax get and the other one for the timer. These functions are called in a setinterval function. However, this does not work properly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function random_user() {

            /*ajax request*/
            $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "random_user.php",
                async: "false",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#random_user').html(data);
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });

            /*Countdown script*/
            function countdown() {
                var counter = 60;
                var interval = setInterval(function () {
                    counter--;
                    if (counter <= 0) {
                        clearInterval(interval);
                        return;
                    }else{
                        $('#time').text(counter);
                        console.log("Timer --> " + counter);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }

            /*Final function call*/
            setInterval(function () {
                random_user();
                countdown();
            }, 60000); //60000 milliseconds = 60 seconds
        }
    </script>


    <ul class="accordion">
        <li>
            <a>1 user - <span id="time">60</span> sec</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <div id="random_user"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Any help is highly appreciated since I am relatively new to php and javascript. 
Best regards

Comment: "does not work properly" -> Can you explain a little bit more since it's really vague here.

Comment: Sorry,  the timer is not triggered right from the beginning. I have to wait 60sec before the countdown starts working... in addition over time there is an overlay of different countdowns + the ajax stops getting data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two separate intervals. Your countdown timer can call `random_user()` if counter==0.

Finally simply start the countdown after the succesful ajax request.

```
 window.onload = function random_user() {

   /*ajax request*/
   $.ajax({
     type: "get",
     url: "random_user.php",
     async: "false",
     success: function(data) {
       $('#random_user').html(data);
       console.log(data);
       countdown();
     }
   });

   /*Countdown script*/
   function countdown() {
     var counter = 60;
     var interval = setInterval(function() {
       counter--;
       if (counter == 0) {
         clearInterval(interval);
         random_user();
       } else {
         $('#time').text(counter);
         console.log("Timer --> " + counter);
       }
     }, 1000);
   }
 }
```

Comment: "First, the variable you're assigning the setInterval function should be a global variable so you're able to clear the interval." Are you sure? setInterval's callback function retains a reference to countdown's lexical environment (closure). Works for me when counter & interval are function-scoped. They do not seem to have to be global variables.

Comment: Good catch AnonEq - that's true. My head was in another programming language where this ain't possible.

Comment: Glad I could help Jakob!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this as well

```
function randomUser() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "random_user.php",
            async: "false",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#random_user').html(data);
                scheduleNext()
                startCounter();
            }
        });

    }

   function startCounter() {
    const counter = 1;
        setInterval(() => {
            $('#time').text(counter);
            counter++;
        }, 1000)
    }

    function scheduleNext() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $('#time').text('getting next user...');
            random_user();
        }, 60000)
    }

    randomUser();
```